# How do I call function in select function in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on `LINQ` but I got a problem when I am  calling `CheckValuedoubleOrNot()` function with in select query in `LINQ`.

How can I call a function within select Query in LINQ?
`CheckValuedoubleOrNot` is function which I am using in select statement.

I am getting Error in this line:

```
listBoardData.Select(CheckValuedoubleOrNot(x=>x.FromDuration)==false));

public ActionResult CheckValuedoubleOrNot(dynamic value)    
{
    double price;
    dynamic returnType;
    if (Double.TryParse(value, out price))
    {
        returnType = price;
    }
    else
    {
        returnType = false;
    }
    return returnType;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic` instead of `object`? If you are passing a value that is not a double, you will get an exception. And `ActionResult`does not make any sense. If you want to check if a value is a double, use `value is double`.

Comment: yes you are right but after changing the return type "ActionResult" to "dynamic" then there is same issue when i am calling the function

Comment: Don't just make code changes to make errors disappear. _Understand_ what's wrong and make the _right_ changes.

Comment: i am using dynamic because i am not clear function return ""Price value:90.0" or may be function return false

Comment: Don't do that. If you have different return types, use different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why are u using `Select`? I would suggest to use `Where`, something line this:

```
public class DoubleResult
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set;}
    public double Result {get; set;}
}

public DoubleResult CheckValuedoubleOrNot(dynamic value)    
{
    double price;   
    if (Double.TryParse(value, out price))
    {
        return new DoubleResult { IsValid = true, Result = price };
    }
    else
    {
        return new DoubleResult { IsValid = false };
    }
}

listBoardData.Where(x => !CheckValuedoubleOrNot(x.FromDuration).IsValid)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want something like this:

```
listBoardData.Select(d => CheckValuedoubleOrNot(d.FromDuration)))
             .Where(v => !v);
```

In `Select` you remap elements of collection to `IEnumerable<ActionResult>`, elements which are double or bool. In `Where` you sift out false values and take only double elements.

Answer (score 0):

Issued Resolved

listBoardData.Select(x => CheckValuedoubleOrNot(x.FromDuration) !=null );

public static double CheckValuedoubleOrNot(string value)
        {
            double price;
            double returnType=0.0;
            if (Double.TryParse(value, out price))
            {
                 returnType =price;
            }
            return returnType;
        }

There was a two reason i got a Error

1. I was using return type ActionResult which is not relevant according to function.
2. I was not using static Keyboard

Thanks